# Using for loop not able to get all the values of text boxes when submit button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I created text boxes using for loop, each row has a submit button. When submit button is clicked, all the values entered in the text boxes must be displayed. I'm able to print only the last column text box value in a row. How to get the value of other text boxes.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def display_text(w):
    print w.get(1.0, END)
    print x,y


for x in range(4):
    for y in range(3):

        w = Text(root, width=15, height=2)
        w.grid(row=x,column=y)
        w.insert(END,'')

        b=Button(root,text="Submit",command=lambda w=w: display_text(w))
        b.grid(row=x, column=y+1)

root.minsize(400, 400)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your other `Submit` buttons are covered by `Text` widgets.

Replace your line

```
b.grid(row=x, column=y+1)
```

with

```
b.grid(row=x, column=y+3)
```

to make them visible. It will place 3 Text boxes, next to 3 Submit buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating 3 submit buttons in each row but 2 of them are covered by the text boxes, so you can only see the last submit button.  That is why you get only the content of last text box.  In order to print all the content of text boxes in a row, you only need to create one submit button in each row and pass the list of text boxes to the command function as below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def display_text(wlist):
    for w in wlist:
        print(w.get(1.0, END))
    print(x,y)

for x in range(4):
    wlist = []  # hold the text boxes in current row
    for y in range(3):
        w = Text(root, width=15, height=2)
        w.grid(row=x,column=y)
        w.insert(END,'')
        wlist.append(w)
    b=Button(root,text="Submit",command=lambda wl=wlist: display_text(wl))
    b.grid(row=x, column=y+1)

root.minsize(400, 400)
root.mainloop()
```